# aws ec2 describe-instances is returning empty array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am using AWS CLI on Windows (eu-west-1). There is an EC2 instance there but when I look for it with:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

and also

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1 --instance-ids x-xxxxxxxx
```

I get an empty array and error:

> An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: The instance ID 'x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist.

Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Check which aws profile is being used, if you don't pass one, default profile is used, and highly suspect a wrong account is being queried

Comment: which profile in the aws cli? its mine

Comment: use aws sts get caller identity to see if your call uses the correct credentials

Comment: What if you just use `aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1`? If that does not provide a result, and you know that there is an instance in eu-west-1, then your AWS CLI is using a set of credentials associated with a different AWS Account. That is why it cannot see the instance.

Comment: Ok so I think I see the issue. I am logged in as correct user but each environment has a different account number. How do i add that account to the describe-instances command?